# Visibility of browsing history to ISP

Tags: router, isp

I was reading an [article](https://www.indiatoday.in/technology/features/story/do-airtel-jio-act-spy-on-fiber-internet-users-isp-supplied-routers-raise-privacy-digital-rights-concerns-1844534-2021-08-24) discussing the deleterious effects of ISPs locking down customers with mandatory antiquated routers supplied by the very same ISP while providing *fiber-net* connections. One point in this article that I didn't quite understand is when one of the advocates against this issue mentioned that the ISP could possibly snoop on the user's browsing behavior (emphasis mine).

> From a privacy perspective, **Airtel<sup>[*]</sup> should not have access to what I am
> accessing on the internet**.

<sub>*Airtel is the ISP</sub>

Doesn't the ISP(Airtel in this case) anyway know the domain which I'm browsing because, well, it's my ***ISP***? This [DuckDuckGo](https://spreadprivacy.com/protection-from-isp-spying/#:%7E:text=ISPs%20can%20still%20see%20the%20domain%20of%20the%20website%20you%20are%20visiting%20(everything%20up%20to%20the%20%27/%27).) article appears to indicate that the domain name of the site is anyway visible to the ISP, even in case of HTTPS sites. What additional information can the ISP glean from the router that isn't already available with it?

Comment: Also check [security.se]. There might be an answer over there already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Having reviewed your article, yes there is some concern related to using an ISP controlled router/gateway; primarily that because the router is positioned between the LAN and the WAN, and because the company has control of it, they can see into the users LAN. They can also prevent you from doing things like establishing site-to-site VPN tunnels using strong encryption, or filter traffic they don't like.

This concern is a little different than many of the other concerns raised by ISP visibility into traffic as it passes through their systems. @Frederic Loyer raised some of those concerns, including logging DNS queries, and performing packet inspection. An ISP can perform these tasks regardless of whether they provide the connection router or not. In these cases strong encryption is the correct response, using secure circuits like VPNs or TOR. TLS/SSL also provides some degree of protection, but does reveal more about the connection to observers (in particular destination IPs and Hostnames) than persistent tunnels like VPNs.

The easiest way to deal with an ISP having insight into your LAN (via a provided router), is to install your own router between your network and the ISP router.  This will prevent them from being able to see systems within your LAN, but still allows them to see your traffic, once it has passed on to their network. From your own router, you can use the full range of features you want to, including strong VPNs, but you may not be able to deal with filtering upstream by the ISP device.

Combining a personal router and a VPN is probably the best route you can take to limit ISP visibility into your comings-and-goings. It does not completely remove you from view, but its about the best a regular consumer can do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I didn't quite understand the part where site-to-site VPN tunnels could be prevented when using ISP-controlled routers. What allows them to do that? Could you please help elaborate on that or direct me to some resource where I can look it up? I have an idea of what site-to-site VPN is.

Comment: so routers generally allow you to enable functionality via some form of shell (a web gui or a command shell on ssh or telnet). if they configure the firmware to remove features, or select a hardware model that doesn't support creating VPN connections, then you can;t create one. note that site-to-site VPNs are generally configured from the gateway router. if you establish a VPN from a system inside your LAN, that is usually a Point-to-site VPN connection. additionally, the ISP can block common VPN protocols, either at the gateway router, or further upstream within their network.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the ISP DNS address, the ISP can log each domain resolution. You can use the Google DNS address (8.8.8,8), but then Google can log each domain resolution… the main solution is to use its own DNS with a link to root domain DNS servers.

If you send your IP packet directly to your ISP, your ISP can log each destination adreesses. One solution is to use a VPN, then all what your ISP will see will be traffic between uou and your VPN provider… but your ISP provider can log each destination adresses. One solution is to use the Tor network. Here no single node will see all your traffic with enough precision.

Comment: `...all what your ISP will see will be traffic between you and your VPN provider… but your ISP provider **can log** each destination adresses.`. The ISP could still log the destination address if I'm over a VPN?

Comment: The destination address seen by your ISP is the VPN provider server address. The true destination is only seen by the VPN provider.

Comment: Using Googles DNS does not prevent an ISP seeing the domain names of the sites you are visiting (although it could make it a little harder for them). Using a VPN, and everything including DNS traverses the VPN pushes the point of possible intervept to your bpn provider.